# Regex Ignore ONLY Commas in a string address

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Is there a way to ignore commas in a string with javascript and REGEX.

Comment: Remove all the commas?

Comment: YES OR IGNORE THEM WITH AN SPACE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ignoring you mean retrieving the string with the commas removed?

```
var string = 'a,string,with,comma'.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Comment: YES REMOVE THE COMMAS AND RETRIEVE THE ADDRESS